# First in list, JSon, C#

Tags: c#, json, list

I receive JSon from server:

1) the number of audio

2..n) info about audio

```
response: [312, {
   aid: 217124599,
   owner_id: 49794861,
   artist: 'Hard Drum and Bass Pump Mix ',
   title: 'жёсткий драм... ',
   duration: 142,
   url: 'http://cs4401.vk.me/u133328801/audios/55c4eefd8b0d.mp3',
   lyrics_id: '66439474',
   genre: 12
}, {
   aid: 217122746,
   owner_id: 49794861,
   artist: 'Drum Trance ',
   title: 'лёгкий драм-транс...',
   duration: 209,
   url: 'http://cs5042.vk.me/u139126516/audios/f5ebe6d0f847.mp3',
   lyrics_id: '66430452',
   genre: 12
}, ...
```

I make next:

1) Create scheme JSon

2) Get value

```
        public class JSonR
        {
            public List<Audio> response { get; set; }
        }

        public class Audio
        {
            public int aid { get; set; }
            public int owner_id { get; set; }
            public string artist { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public int duration { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string lyrics_id { get; set; }
            public int genre { get; set; }
        }    

        var RespS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonR>(responseFromServer);
```

How I can get first number: 312?

Comment: have you tried `RespS[0].aid`?

Comment: @w0lf, problem is (and this is not obvious) is that there is a number before the first `Audio` object. He wants that first number.

Comment: It's not JSon. It's JSON

Comment: @ColeJohnson dOse IT maTTeR? Yeah, it's an acronym, but even the library has `JsonTextReader`.

Comment: @gunr2171 actually it does. There is a difference between what it's called and how Microsoft titles their Pascal-casing. Do you call XML Xml because it's System.Xml? No. You call it XML because it's an acronym.

Comment: @ColeJohnson What is mean "child => child.ToObject<Audio>()"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Helper Method

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static JToken ReadFrom(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            return JToken.ReadFrom(jsonReader);
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
JToken token = JsonHelper.ReadFrom(responseFromServer);
int number = token["response"][0].ToObject<int>();
```

If I've made a wrong assumption in that `responseFromServer` is a `Stream` and it is really just a `string`, you can simply do this instead:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer);
```

## Difficulty

Because your JSON data uses heterogeneous JSON arrays, you'll need to take an approach like the one I've given above to get the data out. I don't believe there's any "easy" way to make `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonR>` work the way you want.

What you *can* do is this:

```
JToken token = JsonHelper.ReadFrom(responseFromServer);
int number = token["response"][0].ToObject<int>();
List<Audio> audioList = token["response"]
    .Children()
    .Skip(1) //skip over number
    .Select(child => child.ToObject<Audio>())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: "Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected" What is mean? It wanted open file: JObject

Comment: @Zai4ik If this code isn't working, it's because the JSON you posted in your question is incorrect. Edit your question adding in the contents of `token.ToString()`.

Comment: WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/status.get?uid=" + Settings.Default.id + "&access_token=" + Settings.Default.token); WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream(); StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream); string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); reader.Close(); response.Close(); on exit I get string JSON

Comment: What is mean "child => child.ToObject<Audio>()"? say me please!

Comment: @Zai4ik The expression `child => child.ToObject<Audio>()` is a **lambda expression**. It's a little inline function that maps a `JToken child` to the result of `child.ToObject<Audio>()` which is an `Audio`.